# Mask titleLabel of UIButton ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, mask

I try to apply a mask on my label Button. The trouble is that my label changes place, I do not know how to settle this problem.

```
var view : UIImageView = UIImageView(image: im)
view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
self.view.addSubview(view);
view.layer.mask = btn.titleLabel!.layer
view.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

So, my label's button position is `x:0 y:0` (the white square is my background button, so my original position)

Comment: this isn't an objective c question....

Comment: what is the labels superview? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Labels Superview is UIButton

Comment: UIButton has a titleLabel built in for free... Again, what are you trying to achieve with this mask?

Comment: Today, in my main Application I've button like this

http://i.stack.imgur.com/UVp9U.png

But I want a button like this !!

http://i.stack.imgur.com/eAUW2.png

The color of my text is not the same of background My background is a gradation so I can not define a color for each label

I wanted to add an image (my background) and make a mask with my label

Answer (score 0):

Just create a button to perform your task.

```
var button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

By this you will set button at specific position with specific title.

Comment: My button is in the right place , it's my label which moves after the mask

Comment: Could you Explain the need of label, else through button you can set text on it.

Comment: I don't have Other label , I use the label button

Comment: the white square is my background button, if I don't use MASK, my text ( label) is the same place that my background button. But when I use mask (see my code) my text position is 0/0